# Удалить словарь из списка словарей

Tags: python, list, dict

У меня есть список со словарями. Где указано имя человека, откуда и куда он направляется. Но у одного словаря нет значения "from". Как удалить этот словарь из списка?

```
tour = [
  {
    "name": "Александр",
    "from": "Москва",
    "to": "Казань"
  },
  {
    "name": "Алиса",
    "from": "Москва",
    "to": "Казань"    
  },
  {
    "name": "Сергей",
    "to": "Казань"
  }
]
```

Я пробовал сделать это несколькими способами, но ничего не выходит

```
#способ 1
new_tour = [i for i in tour if (i['from'] == None)]
#способ 2
new_tour = list(filter(lambda i: i['from'] != None, tour))
#способ 3
for i in range(len(tour)):
    if tour[i]['from'] == None:
        del tour[i]
        break
```

Comment: `new_tour = [i for i in tour if 'from' in i]`

Comment: _но ничего не выходит_, это не описание проблемы. Будте конкретны: пробую <так>, ожидаю <это>, а получаю <не то, что ожидал; или ошибку>.

Answer (score 4):

```
keys = {'name', 'from', 'to'}

valid_tour = list(filter(lambda d: d.keys() == keys, tour))
print(valid_tour)

# ({'name': 'Александр', 'from': 'Москва', 'to': 'Казань'},
#  {'name': 'Алиса', 'from': 'Москва', 'to': 'Казань'})
```

Comment: Тогда уж: `{'name', 'from', 'to'}` :)

Comment: @gil9red, как скажете!

Answer (score 3):

Если хотите оставить решение своим способом, можно такой вариант:

```
for i in range(len(tour)):
    if "from" not in tour[i].keys():  # проверяем есть ли ключ "from" в ключах словаря
        del tour[i]
        break
print(tour)
```

Answer (score 2):

Починил вам все три способа, хотя, в общем-то, это уже сделали до меня по отдельности в разных ответах и комментариях:

```
#способ 1
new_tour = [i for i in tour if 'from' in i]

#способ 2
new_tour = list(filter(lambda i: 'from' in i, tour))

#способ 3
for i in range(len(tour)):
    if not 'from' in tour[i]:
        del tour[i]
        break
```